# Select row above and row(s) between next matching row or last row

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, select, join

This might be a doozy of a question or I might be asking too much at once:

**In a Nutshell**
How can I SELECT rows from a table between two occurrences of "description like 'B/O INFO %' or between 'B/O INFO %' and the last row of a given order number (WHERE OrderNo = 12345678)

**Background**
I am attempting to put together an open order line item report for a client of our business. The database I'm working with old, but "tried and true" and its design and the processes that write to it should be considered immutable for the purposes of answering this question (primarily because the processes that write data to this table are difficult to deal with {COBOL on a Unisys mainframe, mainframe to MSSQL replication, no fully qualified Unisys mainframe COBOL programmer available, migrating *off* the mainframe, etc.}).

What I've been trying to accomplish for 2 weeks now is to create a SELECT statement that returns a hierarchy of orders and order line items. This hierarchy represents an order placed by our client(s) and all the spawned "child" orders attempting to fill (wholly or partially) line items from the "root" order.

When an order is placed many automated and manual processes are applied to it. If the system sees an order line item can be wholly fulfilled by shipping from a different warehouse, it'll create a new child order for those line items. If a line item quantity is unavailable, it'll partially ship and create a backorder for the remainder. If the client *really* needs the line item, a human will manually create a new order sourcing the part from a different location.

**Problem**
The frustrating situation is a non-indexed char(21) column is used to declare what line items in child orders apply to a given parent order and that that linking information is not on the same line as the actual product ordered - it's a completely separate "comment" line. What I'm having *real* trouble with is trying to SELECT specific order line items from these child orders. The most troublesome being SELECTing order line items *between* two instances of a matching description pattern or the end of the order lines.

I've tried all manner of JOINs and WHEREs etc. I'm no DBA, but I'm well above the level "knows enough to be dangerous" and I've come to the end of my understanding trying to get this together.

**What I Need/Want to Do**
Create a stored procedure that returns a result set of all order numbers and their respective item numbers in the order hierarchy I can then use to determine quantity fulfillment of the root order's line items.

**Details**
The way these comment lines in child orders relate to their parents is as follows:

1. A description starting with "@???/" means a child order (see #2 below) has been created with the order number matching the digits between slashes.
2. A description starting with "MEO INFO" means all the items in the order (see #1 above) are related to the order matching the numeric portion of the description.
3. A description starting with "*S/" means a child order has been created (see #4 below) with the order number matching the digits between slashes.
4. A description starting with "B/O #" means the line above is relevant to the order matching the numeric portion of the description. (see #3 above)
5. A description starting with "B/O INFO" means at least one line below until the next occurrence of "B/O INFO" or the end of the order line items is relevant to the order matching the numeric portion of the description. The parent will not have a reference to this child order.

- Orders containing line comments like "B/O  #" or "B/O INFO" can be "composite" child orders fulfilling order line items from one or more parent orders. Associated line items as detailed in the above list.
- Finding "@???/" and "*S/" lines in an order are easy references to child orders.

With this sample data, the root order number is 12345678 and I need to build a hierarchy of all related child line items.
**Sample Data**

```
OrderNo |ItemNo |Description   |LineCD
-------------------------------------------------
Lines pointing to child orders
12345678 1  @LVL/11223344/001
12345678 2  *S/11335577/12345ELEM

All lines relevant to parent order
11223344 1  MEO INFO 12345678
11223344 2  RAIL
11223344 3  BODY OVEN WELD ASM

Comment lines indicate above line is for a parent order
55667788 1  PUMP&MOTOR
55667788 2  B/O #  12345678      
55667788 3  *S/22446688/12345GLAS
55667788 4  B/O #  77553311 //The above line is NOT related to 12345678

Comment lines indicating line(s) below until end of lines or
next comment are for a parent order
98765432 31  B/O INFO 12345678  C
98765432 32  CNTRL-ELEC
98765432 33  STRIKE
98765432 34  CONTROL-ELECTRICAL
98765432 35  B/O INFO 88664422  C
```

I hope this question is answerable. If not, it'll at least give your brain a good work-out.

Comment: it seems you are basically asking us to solve your problem for you?

Comment: Well, I'm leaving out the entire procedure I've written so far - the question WAS getting rather long.

My biggest problem is trying to do a select between one occurrence of "B/O INFO" and the next "B/O INFO" or the last of the order line items.

If anyone can present a way to do that, that'd probably solve this right quick.

Comment: Not the snappiest of StackOverflow questions.  Perhaps the "one other programmer" interested in this question is sitting next to you?  Can you at least cut to the jist like... at all??

Comment: Sorry, quite new to the "ask the community" scene and I like to provide information rather than just blindly ask. Maybe that's the problem - I didn't. I added a summarized request to the top.

Comment: Is this your neck of the woods?  http://www.dbnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/topic20021.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what a mess.

Although I hate recommending the use of cursors, I don't see any other way to get the data you want.  I don't think standard set based operations (selects with joins etc) are going to pull the data in any reasonable matter.

Which leaves us with 3 potential solutions.

One, do the processing in your code.  This has many obvious drawbacks depending on the size of your data set.

Two, do the processing using cursors.  Cursors are not very performant, but with your data structured that way performance isn't even on the radar.

Three, use some type of CLR based solution.  The drawbacks here are your ability to install it and whether your sql server supports that.

Good luck.

Comment: After trying to get this done for more than two weeks, I've come to the conclusion that, indeed, the solution is to step through each order line item in some procedural way (in code, using a cursor, etc.).

But I've also discovered that our database design and the number of different ways an order can be placed make a total solution to the problem essentially impossible (if not extremely ugly with a capital 'F').

Answer (score 0):

That is treally complex and I'm not sure I've fully understood it but I think good output would look like:

ParentID ChildID ItemNo Description (as a resultset)

with all B/O, B/O INFO and S/ translated into parent/child relationships, and parent ID blank for root orders.  This requires a table of order lines (and relationships) to be built in memory during a single pass through the source table.

If building it up in memory is not acceptable, and you have performance issues, I suggest you consider outputting this single resultset instead with two passes:

ChildID ItemNo Description (with S/ B/O B/O INFO filtered out)

UNION

ChildID ItemNo Description (with ItemNo always zero and Description set to ParentID)

If you *have* to put the result somewhere temporarily it should go in another table space.

And validate the parent-child relationships in the consumer of the resultset output (eg Excel or your DSS package).

This way at least some translation/compaction/rationalisation is occurring, the network use is reduced and the key fields are less kind of well, obfuscated.  This *may* be a better solution but it is not clear from the question what the priorities and issues are.

This sounds very like real life.  An elegant (and probably even recommendable) solution free zone.

**EDIT**

It may be harder than I was suggesting to bring the network use down.

In the two-pass solution, I suggest the B/O subsections are given keys like

97387326   (before B/O or B/O INFO section)

97387326-1 (part of first B/O or B/O INFO section)

97387326-2 (part of second B/O or B/O INFO section)

(etc)